# Do we care or do we not care about beauty?

Tags: midrash, parashat-chaye-sara, mishlei, beauty

[Rashi Breishis 23:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=282) says that when Sarah was 20 she was beautiful as when she was 7. Mishlei 31:30 says שקר החן והבל היפי אשה יראת ה' היא תתהלל. Why is Rashi saying that Sarah was beautiful if it is vain?

Comment: Isn't the whole passage about the Jewish people metaphorically and not women in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Pele Yoetz](http://www.peleyoetz.com/PeleYoetz.aspx?ID=174&t=&Search=) answers this question by saying that if one can get a beautiful wife and she is also fearing of God then that is the best combination. I think he says the reason is that a pretty wife will help her husband from sinning.

The rule of שקר החן is for someone who cannot find any God fearing wife except a non-pretty one, in that case we say שקר החן.

Comment: So basically, beauty is only important if you have any. How lovely.

Comment: @DoubleAA Beauty is an extra virtue but not as important is Yiras Shomayim.

Comment: I never contended to the contrary.

Comment: The link leads me to a "page not found" page on itorah.com. Maybe you'd do better with a link [from HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14115&pgnum=158), or [from Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pele_Yoetz.172.1).

Answer (score 2):

See Mishna and Gemara in Taanit 26a, 31a

> ומה היו אומרות בחור שא נא עיניך וראה מה אתה בורר לך אל תתן עיניך בנוי תן עיניך במשפחה (משלי לא) שקר החן והבל היופי אשה יראת ה' היא תתהלל
>
> DO NOT SET THINE EYES ON BEAUTY BUT SET THINE EYES ON [GOOD] FAMILY. GRACE IS DECEITFUL, AND BEAUTY IS VAIN; BUT A WOMAN THAT FEARETH THE LORD, SHE SHALL BE PRAISED.
>
> מיוחסות שבהן היו אומרות בחור וכו':  תנו רבנן יפיפיות שבהן מה היו אומרות תנו עיניכם 
>   ליופי שאין האשה אלא ליופי
>
> THOSE OF THEM WHO CAME OF NOBLE FAMILIES EXCLAIMED, 'YOUNG MAN etc.' Our Rabbis have taught: The beautiful amongst them called out, Set your eyes on beauty for the quality most to be prized in woman is beauty;

So, beauty is also an argument.